# Similarity of 2 Similar Objects

Tags: geometry

Both buckets are similar . Height of the smaller bucket is 12cm and base area of larger bucket is 504 $ cm^2$ . If both buckets are filled with water at the same rate , the smaller bucket can be completely filled 8 times faster than the larger bucket .
Find the height of the larger bucket .

How do I do this when I do not know the base area of the smaller bucket ? I'm confuse . Can I get a hint . Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You have $V_1/V_2=8$ so that, from similarity, $h_1/h_2=2$.

Answer (score 0):

@EmilioNovati sas the answer already. I just add in some details.

Notation:- All measurements are subscripted for ease of reference to the two similar objects. For example, $r_1$ & $r_2$; $A_1$ & $A_2$; $V_1$ & $V_2$; and $R_1$ & $R_2$; are their radii, base areas (or even curved surface areas), volumes and their rates of increase in heights respectively.

When two objects are similar, we can assume that all the corresponding 1-dimensional measurements (e.g. radii, diameters, heights (and even perimeters) etc and collectively known as L) are k times bigger than the corresponding of other (i.e. $r_1 = kr_2$, $h_1 = kh_2$ and $L_1 = kL_2$. Then we have the following commonly known facts:-

$\dfrac {V_1}{V_2} = \dfrac {\pi (r_1)^2 (h_1)}{\pi (r_2)^3(h_2)} = … = k^3 = \dfrac {(L_1)^3}{(L_2)^3}$.

Similarly, $\dfrac {A_1}{A_2} = \dfrac {(L_1)^2}{(L_2)^2}$.

That is the reason why we don’t need to know anything about the base radii/areas.

If we let t be time taken to fill the object, then $\dfrac {R_1}{R_2}$ is just $\dfrac {\dfrac {V_1}{t}}{\dfrac {V_2}{t}} = \dfrac {\dfrac {(h_1)^3}{t}}{\dfrac {(h_2)^3}{t}} = \dfrac {(h_1)^3}{(h_2)^3}$ in disguise.